# How to map AWS ressources to terraform code

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

When I define terraform code for AWS resources I have not used before, I am sometimes unsure about how to define my components. I then often just `apply` any component and modify it using the AWS GUI. Then I use `terraform plan` to see my changes and adapt my code, so that it corresponds to the existing AWS infrastructure.

I wonder whether there is a more direct way to use the AWS GUI to define terraform code. Is there any way to just map an existing AWS infrastructure to terraform code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is `terraform import`

Terraform is able to import existing infrastructure. This allows you take resources you've created in aws via the GUI and bring it under Terraform management.
The current implementation of Terraform import can only import resources into the state file. It does not generate configuration. This will however enable you to then configure your resources

This is how to import an instance with ID `i-abcd1234` to address `aws_instance.bar`

```
terraform import aws_instance.bar i-abcd1234
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/

Comment: Thanks. I really look forward to the future version, which will not only import it as state, but as configuration >> https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/#currently-state-only